# Is there an R function for merging two dataframes by ratio

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two datasets like below.

```
df1=data.frame(o=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))
df2=data.frame(o=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), ratio=c(0.75,0.25,0.25,0.75,0.5,0.5),
               d=c('a','b','a','b','a','b'))

> df1
   o
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  2
6  2
7  2
8  2
9  3
10 3
11 3
12 3

> df2
  o ratio d
1 1  0.75 a
2 1  0.25 b
3 2  0.25 a
4 2  0.75 b
5 3  0.50 a
6 3  0.50 b
```

Values in column 'o' in both dataframes are the same values.
I want to merge two dataframes by column 'o' in both dataframes and ratio in df2 like below(hand made).

```
> df_final
   o d
1  1 a
2  1 a
3  1 a
4  1 b
5  2 a
6  2 b
7  2 b
8  2 b
9  3 a
10 3 a
11 3 b
12 3 b
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea. We can join the data first, calculate the number for each letter and create list based on the length, and then unnest the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% count(o), by = "o") %>%
  mutate(n2 = n * ratio) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(d2 = list(rep(d, n2))) %>%
  unnest(cols = "d2") %>%
  select(o, d = d2)
df3
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#      o d    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#  1     1 a    
#  2     1 a    
#  3     1 a    
#  4     1 b    
#  5     2 a    
#  6     2 b    
#  7     2 b    
#  8     2 b    
#  9     3 a    
# 10     3 a    
# 11     3 b    
# 12     3 b
```

Comment: Similar: `df2 %>% left_join(df1 %>% count(o), by = "o") %>% mutate(n = n * ratio) %>% uncount(n) %>% select(-ratio)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. You guys saved my life.